Investigating stability of oscillating system with no 0dB point at AC response
There is a current driver which was built. As you can see in the links in time domain the system is oscillating.
In control theory we test stability by gain and phase margin of the AC response.
However there is no 0 dB point in the AC response.
How can I see in the AC response that this system will oscillate?




@MathKeepsMeBusy I did that for the asker, because low-reputation users can't embed images.

How did you measure the frequency response? -60 dB or so seems rather suspect.

Hello,you are correct .I made a new AC response where the AC current response in the current on the load divided from the current on the source plot in the links.
Now I see the 0dB mark.How can I see the phase and gain margins and how can I know that I have problems with stability?
https://ibb.co/JdVf8jZ
https://ibb.co/k8wBBY5

Sharing the AC loop response would be helpful -- it's unclear whether you're seeing a valid loop response and misinterpreting it or if you're not calculating the loop response correctly.  I would get the loop response for that circuit by breaking the connection to the "+" input of the op-amp and replacing it with a voltage source.  Experimentally find a voltage that gives you a reasonable voltage across R3, then find the AC response from that voltage source to the voltage across R3.  Then edit your question with that plot, and maybe the schematic.


However there is no 0 dB point in the AC response.

Yes there is: -

It's between 7 MHz and 8 MHz where the gain passes through the 0 dB gain point. But, that is not the point because trying to determine points of instability from the closed-loop AC response is totally a faulty idea...

How can I see in the AC response that this system will oscillate?

Firstly, stick to voltage signal i.e. input voltage and the voltage across R3 (as representing the output voltage) and, open-the-loop to look at the open-loop response. Example method: -

You should use V1 as an AC source but also configure V1 to produce a DC output that is sufficient to begin to partially turn on the MOSFET. This ensures that you are testing the open-loop response at a typical drain current that is representative of your requirements.
Can you take it from here?

Why is it a faulty idea? Barkhausen’s criteria worked last time i checked.

@a360pilot if the closed-loop is unstable you can't perform a valid closed-loop AC analysis because there are massive anomalous signals already present that muddle everything up. So, we open the loop and do an open-loop response. Hence the only valid closed-loop measurement is a transient response and, that will of course tell you that it is unstable but, if you want to know by how much it is unstable, open the loop and check the phase margin.

Why would I see such signals in an AC simulation? I would only see massive peaks that correspond to $T(s) = -1$ or $\vert A_{CL}(s)\vert = \infty $.

Well, if you had a real circuit and tried it you would see an oscillating signal and your intended injected signal and, given that a simulator tries to emulate real devices and circuits, what can you really expect to see @a360pilot

That makes sense, but the original question here is merely addressing the problem in a simulator, and that is why I was confused about your sentence. Thanks for clarifying!

Hello ,I opened the loop and put the excitation there.
I did as you told me and plots AC responce of the current on the load  divided by the current on the source.Two questions:

A photo of V1 definition is attached.You said I should add DC value to this source.you turned off tottaly the original source V1 and put it in the  loop .
How can I know what voltage should I put.
2.at 6MHzI have zero dbm and -364 phase how do I convert this open loop data into the phase gain margin at original closed loop?
Thanks.

https://ibb.co/KNG7jLN
https://ibb.co/nDth87f
https://ibb.co/N34f0LW

You should begin a new post that opens the new question and images to the whole floor. This best serves your interest.

Not sure what's the output in your frequency response result. I guess the input is V1. Maybe the output is the current of the coil or it's something else.
But analyzing the closed loop frequency response to find is it stable or not is a huge math challenge, because you must find indirectly what your circuit does when the feedback loop is opened. It's better to analyze the circuit as the feedback loop opened. The first idea is to analyze this:

V1 is the input and voltage Vo is the output. If at some frequency the phase shift between Vo and V1 is 0 degrees, 360 degrees or a positive or negative multiple of 360 degrees and at the same frequency Vo/V1 is more than 0dB, it builds up an oscillation at that frequency.
To make that analysis you should insert a resistor, say 20...100 kilo-ohms between the non-inverting input of the opamp and node Vo. In addition feed voltage V1 through a capacitor (say 10 nF) to the opamp input. See the next image (it's only a drawing, I don't have your analysis software):

These are needed because the circuit must find a DC operating point before any successful AC analysis is possible.
If it happens that your circuit is made to control the coil current with voltage V1 it looks (by pure intuition) non-efficient mess. I would drive the coil with a cathode follower. It, of course, generates only one current polarity, but your circuit is as limited. 10 ohm and 100 ohm resistors seem to dissipate substantially. No idea of the reasons of such values.
The instability of your circuit can be guessed, because the coil n series causes some phase lag and the opamp and and the fet amp stage easily cause both tens of degrees phase lag at high enough frequency. As the frequency grows the feedback finally turns positive, but there can still be some gain. And there is, as your time domain simulation shows.

Instead of inserting an additional resistor between Vo and the non-inv. opamp input the DC operating point remains unchanged when you insert the test source V1 directly BETWEEN Vo and the inv. input. This is the most simple and most accurate method for measuring the loop gain - provided the closed-loop loading properties remain unchanged when the loop is open. This is the case due to the very high input impedance at the nin-inv. input. This method is based on Middlebrooks method for simulating the loop gain.

Thanks for the rectification. I do not insert to the answer, because I should prove how to exactly use it in a valid way or show a reference. Maybe you can write an answer with those details.

@oneprivate-  the mentioned method (test source between the opening nodes) is the most commonly used method and was described/applied pretty often in this forum.

I tried to figure out what inserting the test source between the opamp input and Vo causes. I cannot get around the next image https://i.sstatic.net/XIyS39Sc.png. Test voltage Vt is summed to the output voltage Vo. The transfer function Vo/Vt is not the wanted loop gain AB.

@ oneprivate - we must strictly distinguish between block diagrams (decoupled withoud loading effects, no DC bias problems) and real circuits which can cause loading effects and which require restauration of the DC bias point. It is a well proven technique for loop gain simulations to open the loop at a point where no severe loading changes will occur and to place the test source BETWEEN the openings. Then, the ratio of the two voltages (left and right to the opening) gives the loop gain (magnitude and phase). The DC bias conditions remain unchanged.

Placing the test source between Vo and the high impedance opamp input causes no new loading and the opamp gets the sum of Vo and the test voltage. That's just wanted by you, but the transfer function Vo/Vt is not the loop gain phasor. There's still the unstability generating feedback loop that you said spoiling the AC analysis totally. How in the hell this can also be the well proven method to calculate the loop gain - except by reversing the transfer function Vo/Vt which is said to be meaningless?

@ oneprivate - here is a link which explains the method I have mentioned.
https://designers-guide.org/forum/Attachments/Loop_gain.pdf.
For detailed explanations you can look for Middlebrooks original paper (mentioned in the linked doc). Please note, that I never have mentioned the expression Vo/Vt you have used. As I wrote - the loop gain is the ratio of the two voltages left and right to the opening caused by the test voltage Vt (but Vt does not appear in the ratio !!). And - of course - the "normal" input signal voltage must be zeroed.

@LvW OK. The inserted source voltage Vt shouldn't be used as the loop input, the loop gain that should be calculated is ratio Vo(Vx in the next diagram https://i.sstatic.net/OlQRslM1.jpg. But there's still the possibly oscillating closed loop which is  said to prevent any plausible AC analysis. Your link skips that problem by saying "it only looks like it still has a closed loop, but actually it's open loop AC analysis" I  DO NOT  believe it.  Time domain analysis shows that an unstable loop oscillates despite the inserted Vt. I have inserted more plausible workaround to my 2nd answer.

@LvW (continued) Found so much obvious rubbish (like your link) about loop gain measurements by using Middlebrook's method that I had finally dig up the original "Measurement of loop gain in feedback systems, 1975". The web contains scanned pirate copies of the article. Middlebrook wrote that the loop gain must be reduced  by inserting a voltage division to the test source so that the total loop gain (=the original + the attenuation caused by the divider) drops below the unstability limit. But the actual loop gain is still measured at the ends of the loop like Vo/Vx  in my previous comment.

@LvW It should be mentioned that Middlebrook handled the theory of making  AC measurements in real circuits. In software the nearest thing is to make transient analyses at numerous frequencies.  The attenuator inserted for stability unfortunately causes some extra loading which distorts the results.  In his publication Middlebrook develops also a variation which applies the ideas of his forthcoming "Extra element theorem" to overcome the difficulties caused by the attenuator.

@ oneprivate - I really dont know what to do with your replies. Why dont you simply follow my comments above? As I wrote already: For loop gain measuremets (ac) open the loop at a suitable point and insert a test source Vt  (1 volt ac) BETWEEN the openings and find the ratio of the voltages at the nodes left and right from the source. This is Middlebrooks method (simplified).

do nothing, but know that the loop is still closed and can oscillate which spoils the operating point and makes the frequency response calculations meaningless. as you said. It's a good idea to realize that they are not always only the others (including me) who are incomplete.

I wrote another answer, because it looks like the questioner expects a way to decide from the closed loop freq.response if the circuit is stable or not, but he is NOT interested in reading suggestions what frequency response he should actually simulate. The interesting thing is "how to decide the stability by starting from the already calculated closed loop frequency response".Period.
I said it's a huge math challenge. That's, of course,true only for me and others who mostly make practical experiments and avoid calculating anything more complex than I=U/R or P=UI. Those, who are fully competent in control and feedback engineering math probably cannot see any difficulties worth mentioning. To write something useful I must accept that challenge and it happens now.
The stability in single feedback loop linear circuits is actually the property of the transfer function. Wikipedia and other text sources say that the s-domain transfer function of an oscillating circuit has one or more poles in the right half of the s-plane. Harmfully we do not have the transfer function as a rational function formula of s, we have only calculated samples of it. The samples (=your curves) are limited to the imaginary axis. We can see that some frequencies between 7 and 8 MHz are boosted substantially, but that doesn't prove it's unstable.
The rational function formula of the transfer function could be examined by using analytical methods, but we do not have it.
Because the stability is the property of the transfer function at least a non-mathematician, like me, can decide that any single loop feedback circuit which has the same transfer function as yours is as stable or unstable as your circuit (see NOTE1). We can easily derive one such equivalent circuit as a block diagram. It's simple and can be analyzed easily. I call it here "Equivalent negative feedback amplifier" or ENFA:

NOTE1: Actually your circuit is not a single feedback loop circuit, but the opamp with its local feedback should be stable, so I dare to continue.
The input and output voltage complex number phasors Vi and Vo obey the next equation:
Vo = A*(Vi-Vo)
We can reversely calculate A if we already have the total transfer function Vo/Vi.
A = Vo/(Vi-Vo) = (Vo/Vi)/(1-(Vo/Vi))
You HAVE the complex phasor Vo/Vi. It's a plot and the value is given in polar format, but it's the needed complex phasor anyway. Your circuit simulator hopefully gives the plot as numeric table or even allows you to write the formulas for the actually wanted plot.
So, you must calculate and draw or let the simulator to calculate and draw function
A = (Vo/Vi)/(1-(Vo/Vi))
In different frequencies so that you can see if there exists a frequency where the magnitude of A is higher than one (= 0 dB) and the phase of A is plus or minus 180 degrees. If such frequency exists, A reverses the phase, the negative feedback is turned to positive and the circuit is an oscillator. The magnitude of A should be higher than 0 dB to actually build up the oscillation at the 180 degrees phase shift frequency.
I tested the shown idea in Micro-Cap with a simpler circuit that I know it oscillates and I know how to make it stable. It's actually a Wien Bridge oscillator with an input voltage source V1 to have an amplifier. The output is node 4 The name of the analysis output voltage variable is v(4).

The frequency response plot does not have any infinite gain frequencies:

But someone who has some experience would say "if it oscillates, the oscillation frequency very likely is about 3900 Hz".
The voltage of V1 is set to zero, but time domain transient analysis shows the buildup of 3900 Hz oscillation. The amplitude is limited by the clipping in the opamp:

The guessed oscillation frequency 3900 Hz happens just in this case be very close, but it was only a guess. I have tried other circuits where such guess was more than 10% off.
We can let Micro-Cap plot the open-loop frequency response of the block A in the ENFA. Micro-Cap allows writing custom equations for the plot.  In AC analysis voltage v(4) is considered as complex number phasor. The amplitude of the input V1 in AC analysis is by default 1, so the total transfer function can be written simply as v(4). The result and the used equations of the plot:

The magnitude of A of the ENFA is just a fraction of a decibel over 0 dB at the oscillation frequency, but that's enough for oscillation.
To make it stable we can reduce the gain by reducing the resistance of R3. It's tried in the next image:
R3 is reduced to 3900 ohms. The new plot of A is in the next image:

It's nearly oscillating, but it's stable, because the magnitude of A is below 0 dB at the phase inversion frequency. Transient analysis shows that the oscillation (kicked to start by turning the circuit ON) decays soon:

The frequency is not changed substantially. The analysis duration is stretched from 5 ms to 10 milliseconds to show the decay better.
Hopefully you can try this with your circuit.
LATE ADDITION: There exists popular circuit analysis programs which do NOT allow writing expressions using complex number phasors of voltages or currents. One of them is CircuitLab which is available just here for free. How to find the open loop response A of the ENFA by using it?
I will show later how to proceed in CircuitLab. It's a side product in my effort to work around the given comments which said "Your closed loop frequency response simulations are meaningless, because in an oscillating circuit there cannot exist any stable operating point".
I said "The circuit could be forced to a stable operating point". I understand it's only hooey as long as I do not have any evidence. But here's the evidence:

Let H be a full closed loop system. If we put it inside the shown feedback loop, the resulted transfer function Y/X is just the wanted A of the ENFA of H. H can be an unstable system but the new system will be stable, because it's transfer function belongs to an open loop system (=A of the ENFA).
This does not need complex number phasor expressions, so we can try it in CircuitLab. We apply it to the same unstable Wien bridge amplifier as we used above.

When the AC analysis was started CircuitLab turned on the green indicator of successful DC analysis. At least CircuitLab believes it's able to do something useful. It's not bulls##t -  the interior loop alone may be unstable, but the exterior loop succeeds to force the circuit to stay stable (see NOTE1). I checked it by running time domain analysis. I double checked it in Micro-Cap. The output stabilized to a constant DC level whenthe input voltage V3 was zero volts. The output DC level was caused by the offset voltage in the opamp model.
The resulted A is the same as what's got in Micro-Cap:

Zooming in shows better the potential oscillation frequency:

NOTE1: I admit there exist circuits which cannot be externally forced to stay stable in time domain simulation, because either the circuit is non-linear in a too tricky way or stabilizing needs non-causal forecasting the future, which cannot happen in time domain simulation nor in real circuits. Intuitively I feel that such circuits (with or without my exterior loop) may have an ability to get locked like a Schmitt-trigger or flip-flop, there's a transmission line or other delay in the loop or there's included a self-oscillating sub-circuit which is out of the external control. Advanced control system theory textbooks obviously contain much useful material of the subject, but it's beyond my knowledge.

@ oneprivate - The first frequency plot is unrealistic (not to say: false) because such a small-signal analysis assumes that the closed-loop has a fixed DC operating point. Obviously, this is not the case for an unstable circuit. Hence, the closed-loop  magnitude response as a result of small-signal ac simulation cannot reveal any instablities. However, the phase response shows a kind of anormality: It shows a positive slope which does not correspond with a stable system.

@ oneprivate - the only purpose of my comment was to point to the fact that any small-signal ac analysis for an unstable system has no meaningful results. This is because such an analysis will compute an artificial (idealized) DC operatng point which is totally unrealistic.

@ one private - I must admit that I have problems to understand your desire. Do you need a prove that any ac-analysis for an unstable system makes no sense ?

To determine stability according to the Barkhausen criterion, the idea is to measure feedback in response to some perturbation in the feedback loop. You cannot measure feedback while the loop is closed, because that feedback is also perturbing the system, and is itself embroiled in the response.
You must break the loop, perturb the system yourself where you made the break, and see what happens on the other side of the break. This will reveal the open-loop response, which is of interest here. It is necessary to ensure that the break is made at a point where the signal has much, much higher source impedance than the following elements, which in your case is easy to find:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Breaking the loop at the green cross is good, because the op-amp's non-inverting input (node X) presents no load to the signal source at junction of L1 and R3 (node Y). The potential at Y is therefore not dependent upon current sourced/sunk by X, so removing this "non-load" doesn't alter the open-loop transfer function.
By contrast, breaking break the loop at the red cross won't yield good results, because L1 and R3 both load the MOSFET's drain, sinking current. By breaking the loop there you suppress that aspect of the loop's behaviour, and the measured response won't accurately represent the loop's transfer function.
After you've broken the loop, you must bias the system with a voltage source at the "input" side of the break, to ensure that the DC operating point of the entire system is sane. You don't want the op-amp output to be saturated against one of the supply rails, and the MOSFET must also be in an appropriate state. This is very hard to do, because the op-amp has extremely high gain, and even microvolts of change at its non-inverting input can send its output off to one or the other supply potentials. Often I duplicate the circuit with the loop closed, to obtain an appropriate DC operating point, and apply the same potential at the break that would be there closed-loop:

simulate this circuit
Here I use a voltage-controlled voltage source V3 to duplicate the potential at the non-inverting input of the closed-loop version, and apply that same potential at the non-inverting input (node X) of the broken-loop circuit. As you can see, this produces the same MOSFET drain potential in both cases, (see voltmeters VM1 and VM2), indicating that our test circuit (bottom) is properly biased, and both MOSFET and op-amp are in their "active" regions.
Source V2 will be my "perturbation", the source to modulate during the AC analysis. Here are the bode plots:


That doesn't look good, it seems that loop gain is 0dB at a few megahertz, and feedback is exactly 0° phase shifted there. This tells us that the output changes in the same direction as feedback, and that feedback is therefore positive at that frequency.

It's worth noting that most power MOSFETs have horrendously large input (gate) capacitance, in the nanofarads, and this will not sit well with a typical op-amp whose output is directly coupled to that gate. Consider placing a resistor between op-amp and gate, to improve the op-amp's stability, while also introducing a dominant pole for compensation. That's R5 here:

simulate this circuit



@oneprivate unstable circuits can still have a calculable DC operating point. You might have to jump through some hoops to make the sim converge, but usually only positive feedback at DC will cause it to fail. Trying to apply Barkhausen to a closed loop is a mistake, not a crime, and not something deserving downvotes. I wouldn't worry about CircuitLab giving you grief, its DC operating point analysis sucks, and you're better off using LTspice or ngspice anyway. The only reason I use it is for its excellent schematics and integration with Stack Exchange EE.

@oneprivate Also, CircuitLab's op-amp models are very pared down, over-simplified to make them work in a browser-based simulator. The models you find in LTspice are far superior, and in my opinion far more trustworthy for AC and transient analysis than CircuitLab. CircuitLab is great for simple circuits, and learning and trying out more trivial designs.

This answer explains why it is risky to attempt to determine the stability of a system from its closed loop Bode plot. An answer by @oneprivate attempts to do precisely that, it attempts to determine the stability of a system from its closed loop Bode plot.
Consider the following Bode plot(s).


These plots look remarkably like those of a simple low pass filter. A keen eye might notice something slightly amiss. However, in circuits made with real components, we would expect slight (or even large) deviations from the ideal graphs we get from assuming we are dealing only with ideal resistors and capacitors with no parasitics. So, what we see here, does not seem like anything terribly out of the ordinary.
However, in reality, the Bode plot(s), above were created from the transfer function:
$$F(s) = \frac{s-10}{(s+2)(s-2)}$$
which is definitely unstable.
By the way, the subtle clue is that the slope of the magnitude graph changes slightly around frequency 10 or 11.
Having highlighted the risk involved in testing for stability via the closed loop Bode plot(s), I will repeat the requests made to the original poster to provide open loop gain and phase plots, from which the gain cross-over frequency, and phase margin may be accurately determined.
